# Subselect in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create a subselect for on column, with a specific count.

Normally that is not a problem, but in this case I need the ID for the current column as a filter.

For example, I have a table `Rooms`:

```
RoomID  Name 
---------------
  1     Room 1
  2     Room 2
  3     Room 3
```

All rooms have clients, for example

```
ClientID   RoomID   ClientName
-------------------------------
   1         1      Client1
   2         1      Client2
   3         2      Client3
```

And there is a `ClientUsage` table, for example

```
ID ClientID StateID
-------------------
1     1       1
2     2       1
3     3       0
```

Now I want to show all rooms, including the count of all clients with (for example `StateID = 1`)

The result should be:

```
ID, RoomID, CountOfClients, CountOfClientsWithStateID = 1
```

The first 3 things are quite easy, using this:

```
SELECT 
    ID, Name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count
     FROM Client
     WHERE (RoomID = T1.ID)) AS ClientCount
FROM  
    Room AS T1
```

But now I need the `Client.ID` as reference to get the state - any ideas how to solve that?

Trying with something like this, but that is not working:

```
SELECT 
    ID, Name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count
     FROM Client AS T2
     WHERE (RoomID = T1.ID)) AS ClientCount,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count
     FROM ClientUsage
     WHERE (ClientUsage.ClientID = T2.ID) AND (StateID = 1)) AS ClientFreeCount
FROM 
    Room AS T1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
SELECT ID, Name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count
          FROM Client AS T2
         WHERE (RoomID = T1.ID)) AS ClientCount,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count
          FROM ClientUsage
          JOIN Client ON ClientUsage.ClientID = Client.ID
         WHERE (StateID = 1)
           AND (Client.RoomID = T1.ID)
       ) AS ClientFreeCount
  FROM Room AS T1
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! But the Result is litle but weird. Now i have as Result: Roomname, CountofClients, CountOfClientsWithStateID = 1 -> Room1, 16, 831 (that is not possible, it should be maximum 16) - in my ClientState Table there are exactly the same Count of Clients. Any ideas? For ALL Rooms its 831 (but there are still only 512 Clients)

Comment: It lacked a condition on the second subselect. Could you try it now?

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT id AS ClientUsageID, 
                roomid AS RoomID, 
                count(cliendid) AS CountClientID,
                StateID AS CountOfClientsWithStateID 
  FROM room R join client C
    ON R.RoomID  =C.RoomID  
    join ClientUsage  CL
    on C.ClientID   =CL.ClientID  
    where StateID=1
```